# How do I access columns from joined tables using Linq, C# in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to join two tables in my controller and pass the result to my view. Trouble is, I cannot seem to be able to access the column values from the joined table once I'm in the view.

I've tried to do a join in my controller, but I have a feeling I'm going in the wrong direction.

Controller:

```
//GET: kurser/stats/5
    public ActionResult Stats()
    {
        var stat = from k in db.kursister
                   join ku in db.kurser
                   on k.kursus_id equals ku.kursus_id
                   select k;

        return View(stat);
    }
```

My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Itucation.Models.kursister>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
   @{ 
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kursus_navn)<br/>
        }
    }
</div>
```

I would expect to be able to get the value of kursus_navn, which is in the kursus table, which is what I'm trying to join with the kursister table. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like in your linq query, you are only selecting the `k` object. Currently you'll get all kursister records that have a matching kursus_id in kurser, but no data from the kurser table.

Comment: because you just select `k` and you can access only property of `kursister` model, so you can not access `kurser` because you have not select this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting the columns of `db.kursister` after joining the two tables. In order to select all columns from both `db.kursus` and `db.kursister` you need to change your `select` statement into this:

```
var stat = from k in db.kursister
                   join ku in db.kursus
                   on k.kursus_id equals ku.kursus_id
                   select new KursisterusViewModel {k = k, ku = ku};
```

Then in view:

```
<div>
   @{ 
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ku.kursus_navn)<br/>
        }
    }
</div>
```

**Update**
Since anonymous type is not supported in a razor page, you need to create a new class like `KursisterusViewModel` to wrap your data into that:

```
public class KursisterusViewModel
{
    public kursister k { get; set; }
    public kursus ku { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the first line of the razor page into this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Itucation.ViewModels.KursisterusViewModel>
```

Assuming that `KursisterusViewModel` class is in `ViewModels` folder.
**Note** that `Select` statement was updated too.

Comment: thank you so much for answering. I've edited my code according to your answer, but now i get this error:  'kurser' does not contain a definition for 'ku' and no extension method 'ku' accepting a first argument of type 'kurser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Lasserh The reason is because anonymous types are not supported in razor pages. I updated the answer. Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Hi @rad, I'm making progress thanks to your help. However, I still get an error. this time it's The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[Itucation.Models.kursister,Itucation.Models.kursus_kursist,Itucation.Models.kurser]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Itucation.Models.KursisterusViewModel]'

I've tried using return View(stat.ToList()); - but apparently that's not it. Do you have any more suggestions up your sleeve?

Comment: Did you apply all the edit that i made? for example did you modify the `select` statement to `select new KursisterusViewModel {k = k, ku = ku};` ?

Comment: You're right, of course. After I read your updated answer properly and updated my code accordingly - everything works beautifully. thank you very, very much.

Comment: Glad it helped.